# how can i know what is the SDK version?

Tags: xcode, sdk

I know it might be very simple
 but I really need to know what is the SDK version?

macOS 10.13.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this GADRequest

```
- (GADRequest *)request {
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];


NSLog(@"Received ad successfully %@ " , [GADRequest sdkVersion] );

request.testDevices = @[
                        kGADSimulatorID
                        ];
return request;
}
```

try this code the in iOS Project And Check the Output something like this

afma-sdk-i-v7.27.0